# Stolen ETH on Ethereum-Wallet DOT info

Tags: ether, wallets, recovery

Apparently Etherum-wallet DOT net is different to ethereum DOT wallet DOT info.

I used the latter and transfered ETH from Cex.io to my wallet address on June 2. It has not arrived. Subsequent emails to both cex.io and ethereum-wallet DOT info have remained unanswered. Is there something specific I need to do to get the balance updated/reflected or have they been stolen?

Comment: https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/87

Answer (score 1):

Do your due diligence. Don't be phished by looking carefully at the web address.

Use Coinbase as an exchange and Mist for a desktop wallet. (Seriously, how hard can this be? Not at all!)

In case the website WAS legit (it's not) and they got hacked anyway, your ETH would be lost. Not if you had a desktop wallet. Get Mist, learn from everyone else that has lost ETH from not taking pre-cautions, and stop blundering.